# ¿como hacer una lista dentro de este rango de fechas?

Tags: c#

```
DateTime MesActual = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month,1);
var anho = DateTime.Now.Year;
var _mes = DateTime.Now.Month;
var Ultimodiames = DateTime.DaysInMonth(anho, _mes);
DateTime MesTermina = MesActual.AddDays(Ultimodiames - 1);
```

Obtengo el primer dia y el ultimo dia del mes actual, pero quiero convertirlo en una lista para asi poder buscar en la base de datos con cada uno de esos valores, a ver si existe algun registro

Comment: Y la pregunta es?

Comment: dentro de ese rango buscar en la base de datos si cada uno de esos dias contiene algun elemento

Comment: Y eso debemos intuirlo de tu pregunta, que se titula _saber el primer dia y el ultimo dia del mes en c#_? Pulsa en [edit]  y amolda la pregunta a lo que necesitas, explicandolo claramente, diciendo que has probado, y que problemas te has encontrado. Todo esta explicado en [ask]

Comment: Todavía no sé que necesitas.

Comment: Es muy fácil de solucionar, exprime un pato.

Comment: Sigo sin entender. Para qué necesitas una lista de fechas, cuando puedes usar `BETWEEN fecha1 and fecha2`?

Comment: La pregunta mejora un poco. Igual no necesitas una lista de dias para buscar en una DB, porque le podes decir buscar desde aca hasta aca y es lo mismo. Es mas, esas cuentas que haces ahi las podes hacer en la DB tranquilamente.

Comment: Vale! pero si una fecha se repite tantas veces, yo quisiera saber cuantos registros existen con esa misma fecha

Comment: Pues `group by fecha` y `count`. Lo que quieres se puede (y diría que se debe) hacer con una simple consulta a la base de datos, lo que quieres que es lanzar una consulta por dia del mes es completamente ineficiente.Otra opción es cargar todos los datos del mes en un datatable, y posteriormente filtrar con Linq, pero yo lo haría con sql

Comment: Gracias @Pikoh lo intentare asi

Comment: Intentalo y si tienes algun problema, abre una pregunta con el sql que estas intentando, asi como un ejemplo de cómo es tu tabla. Suele ayudar mucho a recibir respuestas crear un [mcve] en [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com). Suerte

Comment: He añadido una respuesta a tu pregunta, aunque como te digo, para el caso que te ocupa, es mejor que lo hagas en una única consulta a la base de datos

Comment: @nandreamd96, **[edit] tu pregunta** - los comentarios son temporales.

Answer (score 3):

Aunque ya hemos establecido en los comentarios que para lo que quieres hacer,es mejor usar una consulta directamente a la base de datos, la pregunta sigue siendo válida: *cómo crear una lista de fechas entre dos fechas dadas*. La solución más sencilla es usar [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var listaFechas= Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + MesTermina.Subtract(MesActual).Days)
.Select(incremento => MesActual.AddDays(incremento))
.ToList();
```

**Editado**

A petición de @JorgeLuisAlcantara, analizo este código parte por parte:

`Enumerable.Range` es un método que recibe dos parámetros numéricos, el inicio de la secuencia numérica y su longitud. Para determinar la longitud, lo que hacemos es restar la fecha del último dia del mes de la fecha del primer dia del mes utilizando [`DateTime.Substract`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/8ysw4sby(v=vs.110).aspx) . Esto nos da como resultado un `TimeSpan`,del que nos interesan los dias. En realidad, ahora que lo analizo, debería haber usado `DateTime.DaysInMonth` y el resultado sería el mismo:

```
var listaFechas= Enumerable.Range(0, DateTime.DaysInMonth(anho, _mes))...
```

El resto de la consulta es sencillo. Lo que hacemos es ir seleccionando el resultado de `Enumerable.Range` (un enumerable con los numeros del 0 al numero de dias del mes) y usando `AddDays` sumamos cada uno al primer dia del mes, efectivamente obteniendo asi, un enumerable de todos los dias de ese mes.

Espero que se entienda, si no es asi no tenéis mas que preguntar.

Comment: Excelente respuesta @Pikoh, me queda una duda con respecto  a *Subtract* según la documentación dice que representa una operación de sustracción aritmética que no tiene comprobación de desbordamiento, y sus sobrecargas tienes 2 y 3 parámetros, pero veo que en tu ejemplo sólo hay uno. La verdad no entiendo esa parte, serías tan amable de explicar como funciona?

Comment: @JorgeLuisAlcantara creo que te equivocas de método, yo aqui uso [`DateTime.Substract`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/8ysw4sby(v=vs.110).aspx) que espera como parámetro de entrada un DateTime. Edito de todas maneras la pregunta para explicar que hace exactamente

Comment: Ah confusión mía entonces, gracias por tu ayuda @Pikoh

Comment: @JorgeLuisAlcantara he editado la respuesta, si tienes dudas me dices :)

Comment: Está perfecto, ahora me queda claro, muchas gracias @Pikoh

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas sencillo seria una consulta sql similar a esta:

```
SELECT FROM tabla WHERE fecha BETWEEN fechainicial AND fechafinal
```

Pasar los valores de fechainicial y fechafinal como paramentros de la consulta y revisar dependiendo del motor de la base de datos la sintaxis de la consulta

Comment: Primero,en tu ejemplo no hay columnas en el select, o minimamente `*`. Segundo, en los comentarios el OP especifica que necesita el numero de ocurrencias por cada fecha.

Comment: Tienes razon, seria algo como "select fecha, count(*) FROM tabla WHERE fecha BETWEEN fechainicial AND fechafinal group by fecha

Comment: eso tiene mejor pinta ;)